# Always receive 'invalid client' error using Google Play Store signing from Visual Studio (Xamarin)

Tags: android, visual-studio, xamarin, google-play, google-play-games

I have uploaded my .aab file to Google Play Console using ad-hoc distribution from Visual Studio with no problems previously for my Android app built with Xamarin. However, whenever I try to use Google Play Signing from within Visual Studio it fails. I have created the client IDs in Google Developer Console. I am using the client ID from the release fingerprint but whenever I try to sign with this I receive the error:

Google Play Store: Authorize
Error:"invalid_client", Description:"Unauthorized", Uri:""

One of the problems that I can see is that Visual Studio asks for a "client secret" together with the client ID. However there is no way for me to generate the client secret using Google Developer Console, only the client ID. I have tried downloading the client secret json file from developer console but the actual row with the secret appears to be missing.

How do I get this working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found that it's not possible to use this feature in Visual Studio, here is the answer from MSFT:

> As the OAuth document described, the client_secret is not applicable
> to requests from clients registered as Android, iOS, or Chrome
> applications. So when we select the "Application Type" to "Android"
> option, there will be no client_secret.
>
> The Xamarin publishing document has not been updated for a long time,
> and is not applicable for current publish steps. To publish the
> Android application, please upload the apk to google play store
> manaually.